# Auto mouse left click on webpage

Tags: javascript, php

I want to script that will simulate mouseleft click after webpage load.
I want this click on same webpage itself after load

I try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if($submit)
{
  echo '<body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',1000);">';
  echo "<a id='linkToClick' onclick='return confirmDialog($id);'>clickme</a>";
  echo '</body>';
}

else
  echo 'not set';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
      function autoClick(){
        var myLink = document.getElementById('linkToClick');
          myLink.click();
      }
        function confirmDialog (id, callback) {
        confirmDialogCallback = callback;
        $("#idConfirmDialog").modal ("show");
        }
</script>
```

but it  did not work

Comment: Its working?? `'<body onload="setTimeout('autoClick();',1000);">';` when render your html. What is your code HTML result

Comment: Why do you echo html inside an unclosed script tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can make auto-loading JS functions, by adding parenthesis around a function & another set of parenthesis after the function. Like so:

```
(function autoClick(){
   ... do stuff ...
})();
```

However, I don't recommend making pages auto-click onLoad, nor auto-open & close modal dialogs. Users will find that annoying & not want to visit your site again.

If you're simply attempting to show a modal onLoad after a form button is submitted, then try this:

```
<script>
    (function showModal()) {
        $("#idConfirmDialog").modal("show");
    })();
</script>
```

A better solution would be to use Ajax to submit the form's data back to the server & then present the modal dialog, without a full page-unload.

See jQuery's [$.ajax page](http://api.jquery.com/?s=.ajax) for more details on how to do use Ajax to create a better form saving experience & a faster / more responsive website for the end-user.

Comment: sorry i did not understand you, i am not good developer, can you please explained and write complete code to me.
and related to reason i need to open webpage after click page load, this is ADS webpage

Comment: for more ex , this is test webpage but it is in arabic, if you make click on it anather webpage will open, i want this hapend auto without user click
http://www.floos-online.com/ads